# Implementing volley in an android project

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I wrote some code to send data to a server to be stored in a data base..I'm also using wamp to create a locale server

this is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.jawad.sze;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText ed;
    Button asd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        asd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        asd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.105/sze/add_user.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("response",response);
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "onResponse", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "onErrorResponse", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }){
           @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name",ed.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Map", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return  map;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);


    }


}
```

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jawad.sze"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile  'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

}
```

Log error:

```
05-26 22:56:28.354 4232-4495/com.example.jawad.sze E/Volley: [9108] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
               java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:208)
                   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:122)
                   at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
                   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
                   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
                   at com.example.jawad.sze.MainActivity$1$3.getParams(MainActivity.java:59)
                   at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:434)
                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                   at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

this code used to be working perfectly, i used to put text in the EditText click the button, open phpMyAdmin and the string would be there, but not anymore I did update android studio but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: What is the error or problem that you get now?

Comment: no errors, the data is just not being sent to the server

Comment: In that case use a http debugger like Charles or Fiddler and monitor the http traffic and confirm that the app is not sending the correct data.

Comment: so it's not related to my code? i mean is the code correct?

Comment: Your code seems okay. Did you change anything in your backend?

Also use something like Postman and see whether the Web service works correctly.

Comment: so i added toasts to each listener in my stringRequest and only the error listener is working

Comment: Bingo! That's the problem. Print the error to the log and see what the error is. Only one listener should work at any time!

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Now this error is because you may be trying to call a UI call from another thread other than the UI thread (Also called the Main thread).

Use the following code to decide whether it's the main thread.
"Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()" will return true if the thread is the main thread. Returns false otherwise.

Comment: i didn't really understand that, can you post an answer telling me what to do?

Comment: Is your current code identical to the code above? Have you added something else such as a Toast to the above code?

Comment: Please update the above code if you have made any changes.

Comment: Have you tried compile `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` instead? `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` is deprecated (see GitHub author's note at https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line `Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Map", LENGTH_SHORT).show();` inside `StringRequest#getParams()`

The method in which this is called seems to be called on a thread managed by Volley. Presumably that thread hasn't been started yet, hence the `RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

See https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html on methods to work with the UI from asynchronous services. Creating a toast on such a thread simply doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

}
```

change our `'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` to following

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Comment: oh i just forgot to add that in the question, i fixed the question

Comment: Still you are getting issue ?

Comment: Any error appears in your errorlistener? Is your service are locally stored?

Comment: If you are getting handler error than dont add toast , just use LOGGER to determine your error.